# MongoDb syntax error - invalid property id

Tags: mongodb

MongoDB Shell doesn't make it any easy to find out WHAT is the error and WHERE in the code it is. This code runs perfectly in NoSQL Booster. I have tried many changes, adding quotes here and there. Nothing works.

What property id is he complaining about?

```
db.Logging.aggregate([
{
    "$match": {
        "timestamp": {
            $gte: 1585710000000,
            $lte: 1585882800000,
            $ne : null
    }
},
{
    "$project": {
        dia: { $dateToString : { format: "%d", date : {$add: [new Date(0), "$timestamp"] } }
    }
},
{
    "$group": {
        _id: "$dia",
        "count" : { "$sum" : 1 }
    }
}
]);
```

Comment: You are not making it easy to answer your question by not including the exact  output produced by the shell (including the error message).

Comment: The braces `{}` are not balanced  in the first 2 stages.

Comment: That was it. Why then the error message complained about a property if the problem was with missing braces?